# Response Data for "GET Method"

Tags: jmeter, httpresponse

I am creating different HTTP Requests for a site and taking an access token as a variable from Regular Expression Extractor and using it in another HTTP Request.

The Thread group is working fine; *i.e.* no error in View Results Tree. But Response data is only coming for the Request with POST Method. Nothing is coming for the Request with GET Method and both requests are taking the access token properly.

Comment: can you show your plan and zoom on the post and get resuests and show errors if any ? (all tabs of View Results Tree)

Comment: Now I am getting {"getAvailModesResponse": in Response data of JMeter instead of Getting {"getClientAccountsResponse": which is required response of the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you may get response code 200 ok and request still may fail. In case of your get request that seems to be happening.

Check following:

1. Headers being sent with get request. (Compare request being sent from JMeter and from real browser.)
2. Add response assertion to get request to be assure the correctness of the response. (Check what response you get for the request made from browser.)
3. Make sure you have added cookie manager in the test plan.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use response assertion and cookie manager